# Can I get location of android device without GPRS on server side?

Tags: android, gprs, android-gps

I am trying to get the location of a device without GPRS. Is there any way to communicate with the server?

Is it the case that, it required internet connectivity. I don't want the locate device on a map. I just need its longitude and latitude.

Comment: you can send location as sms

Comment: @droidev you can send locaion as sms but howw do you get the location in the first place? You have to enable location in android device, and this makes use of GPS. So Rohit, the answer is no, you can't pull it off without GPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without sending GPS points.

You have to send GPS point from phone to server via Internet Connection or SMS messaging.